# Remove dt_breaks from a plotly graph

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I would like to plot a ohlc graph removing the gaps (rangebreaks) with no data at different intervals.
Program works well when using daily intervals but I am unable to remove the gaps when using other intervals (1h,30min), process is more or less the same, but only shows the first day.

First I thought it was a datetime format issue but removing "rangebreaks" allows to plot all series.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf
#pio.renderers.default = "browser"
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

t_var = ['META']
end = datetime.now()
start = end - relativedelta(days=59)
df_y = yf.download(t_var, start=start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end=end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), interval= "30m")
d = df_y.index[0]
b = df_y.index[-1]

dt_all = pd.date_range(start=d,end=b,freq='30min')
dt_breaks = [d for d in dt_all if not d in df_y.index]
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
fig.add_ohlc(x=df_y.index, open=df_y['Open'], high=df_y['High'], low=df_y['Low'], close=df_y['Close'],name='stock',decreasing_line_color='#21201f', increasing_line_color='#21201f', row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=True, showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='cursor', showline=False,rangebreaks=[dict(values=dt_breaks)], rangeslider_visible=False)
#fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=True, showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='cursor', showline=False,rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Market holidays that cannot be handled by rangebreak functionality alone can be handled by adding the target period to rangebreak, but the specification did not work. `rangebreak=[dict(bounds=['sat','mon']),dict(bounds=[16,9], pattern='hour'),dict(value=['2023-06-17','2023-06-19'])]` Another approach is to add the current index to the index of 30-minute intervals from the start date to the end date, and extract only the non-overlapping indexes. That extraction is then given to rangebreak. At this time, the base value of dvalue for rangebreak is 86400000msec (1000msec*60sec*60min *24h), so we set it to 1800000 (1000msec*60sec*30min).

```
t_var = ['META']
end = datetime.now()
start = end - relativedelta(days=59)
df_y = yf.download(t_var, start=start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end=end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), interval= "30m")

d = df_y.index[0]
b = df_y.index[-1]

dt_all = pd.date_range(start=d,end=b,freq='30min')

marged_index = dt_all.append(df_y.index)
timegap = marged_index[~marged_index.duplicated(keep = False)]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
fig.add_ohlc(x=df_y.index,
             open=df_y['Open'],
             high=df_y['High'],
             low=df_y['Low'],
             close=df_y['Close'],
             name='stock',
             decreasing_line_color='#21201f',
             increasing_line_color='#21201f',
             row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False,
                 zeroline=False,
                 showticklabels=True,
                 showspikes=True,
                 spikemode='across',
                 spikesnap='cursor',
                 showline=False,
                 rangebreaks=[
                     dict(values=timegap, dvalue=1800000), # 30min:1000msec*60sec*30min
                 ],
                 rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Really elegant the "~marged_index.duplicated(keep = False)" solution

Comment: just a small variation. 
If df is loaded from a CSV  datetime is taken as string. Append doesn't work. I tried some adjustments converting dt_all to a str list but not working.
'df = pd.read_csv('Meta.csv')
marged_index = dt_all.append(df['Datetime'])'

Comment: To convert the time series data you have read, do the following. `df = pd.read_csv('Meta.csv');df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])`

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in how you calculate the dt_breaks. When you are using daily intervals, it works fine because there are no missing data points in a daily timeframe. However, when using smaller intervals like 30 minutes, there may be gaps (missing data) in the data, and the way you calculate dt_breaks is causing an issue.

To fix this, you need to modify the calculation of dt_breaks to find the missing data points and create appropriate range breaks. Here's an updated version of your code

```
  import warnings
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf

#pio.renderers.default = "browser"
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

t_var = ['META']
end = datetime.now()
start = end - relativedelta(days=59)
df_y = yf.download(t_var, start=start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end=end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), interval="30m")
d = df_y.index[0]
b = df_y.index[-1]

dt_all = pd.date_range(start=d, end=b, freq='30min')
dt_breaks = [d for d in dt_all if d not in df_y.index]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
fig.add_ohlc(x=df_y.index, open=df_y['Open'], high=df_y['High'], low=df_y['Low'], close=df_y['Close'], name='stock', decreasing_line_color='#21201f', increasing_line_color='#21201f', row=1, col=1)

# Calculate range breaks for missing data
range_breaks = []
for i in range(1, len(df_y.index)):
    prev_time = df_y.index[i - 1]
    curr_time = df_y.index[i]
    if (curr_time - prev_time) > pd.Timedelta(minutes=30):
        range_breaks.append(dict(values=[prev_time, curr_time]))

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=True, showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='cursor', showline=False, rangebreaks=range_breaks, rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

The modified code calculates the range_breaks based on the time differences between consecutive data points. If the time difference is greater than 30 minutes, it indicates a missing data point, and a range break is created between the previous and current data points. This way, the OHLC graph will not show the gaps caused by missing data.

Please try this updated code, and it should display the OHLC graph without gaps for 30-minute intervals or any other interval you choose.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

I see your approach, removing "range_break" as time windows instead of point by point as I did.

Unfortunately issue persist, only shows the first day (9th June) also 15:30 is missing. Did it work for you?

when appending the "range_break" "prev_time" + 30min

range_breaks[0]: {'values': [Timestamp('2023-06-09 15:30:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
  Timestamp('2023-06-12 09:30:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')]}
 dt_breaks[0]:  Timestamp('2023-06-09 16:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York', freq='30T')
len(dt_breaks): 2199
len(range_breaks) :  38

Comment: the best I could do was using  dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),
removing a bank holiday didn't work {'values': ['2023-06-16', '2023-06-20']} any reason why it fail?

Comment: I don't *know* why a downvote was cast on this post but I would hazard a guess that the downvoter suspected this of being a ChatGPT-generated answer.